# Are there any differences between jasmine and expect?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I watched a tutorial where the author's advice is to use the `expect` framework to write better assertions:
https://github.com/mjackson/expect.

1. But as far as I can see, this is exactly the same as `jasmine`, and jasmine is far better known. Did `jasmine` absorb the `expect` library?
2. Is there any practical difference between the two?

Comment: For other archaeologists like me, "_[This package [expect] has been donated to Jest. This means that all future development of expect v21+ will take place at facebook/jest.](https://github.com/mjackson/expect)_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasmine is a complete testing framework. expect is just the assertions and would be used in conjunction with something like mocha.

On the Jasmine home page:

> BATTERIES INCLUDED
>
> Comes out of the box with everything you need to test your code.

Where as on expect:

> You can think of expect as a more compact alternative to Chai or Sinon.JS

I read this article a few days ago in deciding what to use for a project. It was a good read and insightful. Check section 1 (API) for where expect (or similar? there are two expect libraries apparently) fits in to the picture.

http://thejsguy.com/2015/01/12/jasmine-vs-mocha-chai-and-sinon.html